# Backbone: Uncaught TypeError: cannot read property 'toJSON' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm getting the follow error: "Uncaught TypeError: cannot read property 'toJSON' of undefined"

I bet is stupid mistake (granted doesn't help to focus the fact that my 2 year old daughter is with me), but here I am.

This is my code:

```
(function($){


  // Model:
  //-------

  var DirectoryItem = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: function(){
        title: 'New Company'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        console.log(this.get('title'));    
    }

  });

  var Company1 = new DirectoryItem({title:'Company number 1'});

  // Collection:
  //------------

  var Directory = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: DirectoryItem,

    initialize: function() {
      console.log('New collection created...');         
    }

  });

  var directory = new Directory(Company1);

  // View:
  //------

  var DirectoryListView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $("#directoryView"),

    template: _.template($('#item-list-template').html()),

    initialize: function(){
        this.render();                
    },

    render: function () {
      this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
      return this;
    }

  });

  var directoryListView = new DirectoryListView();

})(jQuery);
```

Someone can help me?

Thanks!

PD: probably you already noticed it but I'm new to Backbone

Edit: as a template I have this:

```
<script type="text/template" id="item-list-template">
    <li><%= title %></li>
</script>
```

Comment: The value of `this` is probably is not what you are thinking it is. What about using `directory.model.toJSON()` rather than `this.model.toJSON()`?

Comment: I agree with @SpencerWieczorek, check the value of `this`.  You could start by putting `console.log(this)` on the first line of the `render` function.  Or throw in a `debugger` there and play around with it in the console until you figure out how to access the model you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I already tried before to change directory.model.toJSON() with the same results. Where is by showing 'this' in the log, it tells me that contains the 'el' element, is the correct context, right?

edit: not the same results, it says: 'Uncaught TypeError: directory.model.toJSON is not a function'

Comment: You're saying `var directoryListView = new DirectoryListView()` rather than `var directoryListView = new DirectoryListView({ collection: directory })`, you'd also want to use `this.collection` rather than `this.model` inside the `DirectoryListView`.

Comment: Thanks mu, now is showing a diferent error: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: title is not defined'. I edited my question showing my template, but I don't see why it gives me that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**. You made a mistake on this line:

`var directory = new Directory(Company1);`

because of `Directory` collection expects an array as first argument but not scalar. So fix this to the following:

`var directory = new Directory([Company1]);`

**Second**. Chnage you `DirectoryListView` class to:

```
var DirectoryListView = Backbone.View.extend({

el: $("#directoryView"),

template: _.template($('#item-list-template').html()),

initialize: function(){
    this.render();                
},

render: function () {
  this.collection.each(function (model) {
      var html = this.template(model.toJSON());
      this.$el.append(html);
  }, this);

  return this;
}
```

**Third.** Change your `directoryListView` initialization to the following:

```
var directoryListView = new DirectoryListView({ collection: directory })
```

Comment: Wow! thank you Artem! that work like a charm! And makes a lot more sense now :P.

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)